# xlib integrated debugging (Tracing)

Tags: gdb, x11, xlib, xorg

Is there any debugging options built-in in the Xlib (libX11.so)? Can I get list of X11 lib calls?

I want to get full trace of xlib function calls from heavy-multithreaded, closed-source program. It is one not-public embedded platform, so I can't use gdb for multithreaded debugging and there is no ltrace on the platform.
Also, this program can't connect to x server over tcp/ip, only unix-socket. I want to do tracing of xlib calls from xlib itself.

ps. Xlib from rather modern xfree or even xorg. from gnu linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [xscope](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg-announce/2009-October/001072.html) to monitor the requests sent over a Unix socket, even when you can't send the X protocol over TCP to be able to use network monitoring tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: hello. will wireshark decode x functions calls?
Is xscope included in default xfree - x.org? which versions?

Comment: Wireshark, like xscope, decodes X protocol requests, not library function calls.   xscope is available from X.Org, but not all distributors include it in their package set.  (Since X11R7.0, X.Org distributes each application separately and lets builders decide which to include, so there isn't really "in default X.Org" these days.   No one really uses XFree86 any more.)

Comment: there are a lot of linux distributions and some of them  are not updated for a long time :)

Answer (score 1):

You might look into xlibtrace, which traces at the interface between Xlib and your code, rather than the X Windows wire protocol.  I've executed a couple of the examples, and it seems to work.

The source is available at http://kev.pulo.com.au/xlibtrace

I had to modify it to get it to compile:

```
diff -u src/libxlibtrace-functions.h.sh.orig src/libxlibtrace-functions.h.sh
--- src/libxlibtrace-functions.h.sh.orig    2009-01-19 23:43:46.000000000 -0500
+++ src/libxlibtrace-functions.h.sh 2016-02-24 13:49:25.155556294 -0500
@@ -81,7 +81,7 @@
    return (t ~ /^[cC][oO][nN][sS][tT][     ]/);
 }

-function isarray(t) {
+function our_isarray(t) {
    return (t ~ /\[.*\]$/);
 }

@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@
        return sprintf("%s", t);
    } else if (isfunctionpointer(t)) {
        return gensub("^(.*\\(\\*)(\\).*)$", "\\1"n"\\2", "", t);
-   } else if (isarray(t)) {
+   } else if (our_isarray(t)) {
        return gensub("^(.*)(\\[.*\\])$", "\\1"n"\\2", "", t);
    } else {
        return sprintf("%s %s", t, n);
diff -u src/libxlibtrace-print-x.h.orig src/libxlibtrace-print-x.h
--- src/libxlibtrace-print-x.h.orig 2009-01-19 22:30:06.000000000 -0500
+++ src/libxlibtrace-print-x.h  2016-02-24 14:27:08.681352710 -0500
@@ -2415,6 +2415,20 @@
    dofflush(f);
 })

+// XGenericEventCookie
+#define __REALTYPE_XGenericEventCookie__    XGenericEventCookie
+#define __REALTYPE_XGenericEventCookie_p__  XGenericEventCookie *
+#define __REALTYPE_XGenericEventCookie_pp__ XGenericEventCookie **
+#define __TRACE_PRINT_TYPE_STRUCT_BODY_XGenericEventCookie__(safetype) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, int, type) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, unsigned_long, serial) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, Bool, send_event) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, Display_p, display) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, int, extension) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, int, evtype) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, unsigned_int, cookie) __PRINT_COMMA__(f) \
+   __TRACE_PRINT_STRUCT_MEMBER__(f, safetype, *value, void_p, data)
+__INDIRECT_CALL_3__(__TRACE_PRINT_TYPE_STRUCT,__LIBXLIBTRACE_PRINT_X_SUFF__,__)(XGenericEventCookie)


 #undef __LIBXLIBTRACE_PRINT_X_BODY__
```